# Fortran compile error -- In function X undefined reference to Y where function is public and use is implemented

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

As stated in the title, when I compile an executable binary from many fortran object files, I experience an error in `W.f90` and `X.f90` of the type:

`In function 'X_mp_average_list_add_': X.f90:(.text+0x2fa): undefined reference to 'Y_mp_vlist_var_new_'`

I saw in a response to a previous, similar question (avoiding necromancy) that this issue was likely a result of either not declaring `vlist_var_new` as `PUBLIC` in `Y.f90` or `W|X.f90` files did not correctly implement `USE: Y, only vlist_var_new`. However, these are correctly implemented in the Fortran files and the compile worked previously, since such time the files have not been changed.

Can someone indicate other potential sources for these errors?

For reference, I'm using the intel fortran compiler v5.1.3.223

Comment: Are you linking in the object file produced when the source containing module Y is compiled?  Check also your stated compiler version.

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. We need more information from you. The error message itself is almost never enough. We need to know the **exact commands** you are executing and typically also **your code**. See also [mcve].